# PHP can't get value from select option HTML

Tags: php, html, forms, web, post

I have a simple form where users can register, and after submiting I want to work with the values to check everything is fine, the problem is that I cannot get some values.

This is the form in **index.php**:

```
<form class="form-detail" action="correcto.php" method="post" id="myform">

      <select name="personaEmpresa" id="personaEmpresa">
              <option class="option" value="empresa">Soy una empresa</option>
              <option class="option" value="persona">Soy una persona</option>
      </select>

      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-text" placeholder="Nombre" required>
      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input-text" placeholder="Apellidos" required>

</form>
```

I have reduced the size of the form to be more concrete. Once I submit the form and go to **correcto.php**, I can perfectly work with **"first_name"** and **"second_name"** but for some reason I am not able to get the value from **"personaEmpresa"**

This is the code on **correcto.php**:

```
<?php

//I cannot get the value from this one
echo $personaEmpresa = $_POST["personaEmpresa"];
echo "<br>";

echo $nombre = $_POST["first_name"];
echo "<br>";

echo $apellidos = $_POST["last_name"];
```

Thank you all very much!

Comment: Try print_r($_POST)

Comment: You're not using JS in conjunction with this, are you?

Answer (score -1):

Did you put a submit type input into the form?

```
<form class="form-detail" action="correcto.php" method="post" id="myform">

<select name="personaEmpresa" id="personaEmpresa">
        <option class="option" value="empresa">Soy una empresa</option>
        <option class="option" value="persona">Soy una persona</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input-text" placeholder="Nombre" required>
<input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input-text" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
<input type="submit" value="">
```

Answer (score -1):

Finally the error was just that the cache of the browser needed to be updated. You can use **classic cache killer** in Chrome or Firefox to solve this.